# Why does this non-linear function make the matrix rank arbitrarily large?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I was reading a paper, and came across this argument: [image: MoS]

`H` and `W` are matrices here, and $\Pi_k$ is a scalar. I am not able to understand what makes the rank of `A` arbitrarily high rank? I don't follow the logic that `log_sum_exp` is a non-linear function so $\hat{A}_{MoS}$ is arbitrarily high rank.

`A` is basically a sum of matrices here, each of those matrices have a bounded rank. How come `A` has infinite rank then?

The equation is taken from this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.03953 (sec 2.4)

Comment: It's hard to see without going into the paper I think. From this, what I can glean is that $\mathbf{A}$ is nonlinear, so $Ax=0$ is not always implied by $\mathbf{H}\mathbf{W}x = 0$. Therefore, if there are any limitations caused by $H$ and $W$, it shouldn't "transfer" to $A$.

Comment: $A$ may have high rank for large $N$ (the language length) while $HW^T$ has low rank bounded above by the embedding size $d$.

Comment: @A.Γ.I don't get it, since **HW**'s rank is bounded by *d*, and so is **exp(HW)**'s. What we are doing is just summing up such terms (like *0.1\*exp(HW) + 0.2\*exp(HW)*). Shouldn't the rank of this resultant matrix be bounded by *d* as well?

Comment: @A.Γ I am referring to $\hat{A}_{MoS}$ to be clear. I agree with you that the rank of $A$ which is mentioned earlier in the paper is bounded by *N*